# problem in getting value of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, object

I am trying to convert collection data into csv, so i am using 'csv-stringify' npm

my code for converting into csv in

```
      ...auditlogs.reduce((rows, data) => {
        const newRows = []
        const newRow = {}
        console.log('data: ', data);
        console.log('data._id: ', data._id);
        console.log('data.actor: ', data.actor);
        newRow[(null, 'Actor')] = data.actor;
        newRow[(null, 'Date')] = data.date;
        newRow[(null, 'Action')] = data.action;
        newRow[(null, 'Data')] = data.object;
        newRow[(null, 'Description')] = data.description;
        newRows.push(Object.assign({}, rowProto, newRow)) 
        const newRowsNoHeaders = newRows.map(row => Object.values(row))
        return [...rows, ...newRowsNoHeaders]
      }
```

result of console.log('data: ', data)  is

```
data =  { _id: 5ae01fa9dc9e47001a92abd4,
          actor: 'Toan',
          date: 2018-04-25T06:26:49.057Z,
          origin: '',
          action: 'Add',
          label: '',
          object:
           '{ _id: 5ae01fa9dc9e47001a92abd3,\n  name: \'Welcome\', __v: 0 }',
          description: '',
          __v: 0 }
```

But when I am trying to get the value it is showing undefined.

> data.actor = undefined

but only `data._id` is giving correct value.

This is a screenshot
[image]

Can some tells me a solution?

Comment: Note that `_id: 5ae01fa9dc9e47001a92abd4` is invalid syntax, as is `date: 2018-04-25T06:26:49.057Z`. Please create a [MCVE] - aside from the syntax errors, your current code does not demonstrate the problem you describe

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. There isn't enough information in the question to determine what the problem is. (It is *probably* a question of timing, but since you don't show the relationship between the code you use to inspect `data.actor` and the code used to assign a value to `data` we can't tell for sure).

Comment: @JaromandaX, but I am getting that. I can show you the screenshot.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have updated my question, please see again.

Comment: @JaromandaX, But how's my syntax invalid? It isn't an object?

Comment: @JaromandaX, `typeof data` is an object, which I am showing you.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have added a screenshot.

Comment: well, that's completely mysterious to me ... will remove my comments coz I can't help with that

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, it is mysterious for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(log))`

works for me.